# Multplication two inputs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

I would like get values from 2 inputs (**NUM_PRECIO_UNITARIO** and **NUM_PORCENTAJE_IVA**) and show diamically the result of multplication in other input (**NUM_VALOR_IVA**) actually this is my html

file.html

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <mat-form-field>                    
        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="NUM_VALOR_IVA" placeholder="Valor IVA" value="{{formDetalleOC.get('NUM_PRECIO_UNITARIO').value * formDetalleOC.get('NUM_PORCENTAJE_IVA').value}}" required>                  
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

file.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createControlItemOC
} 

createControlItemOC() {  
    this.formDetalleOC = this.fb.group({         
        NUM_PRECIO_UNITARIO: 0,
        NUM_PORCENTAJE_IVA: 0,   
        NUM_VALOR_IVA: 0,
    })  
}
```

this is the result in the front

[image]

but in my form the value not change

[image]

Comment: Your template is just rendering a result. If you want to change the model you need to execute code in the component to change the model value, or you need to accept input from the user (e.g. using [(ngModel)]) - but just rendering something to the screen doesn't change anything in the model.

Comment: please could you explain me the solution with more detail I'm new in angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create in function to multiply those values in your component's class

```
calcResult() {
    const o = this.formDetalleOC.get('NUM_PRECIO_UNITARIO').value * this.formDetalleOC.get('NUM_PORCENTAJE_IVA').value; 
    this.formDetalleOC.patchValue({ NUM_VALOR_IVA: o });
    return o;
}
```

In the HTML template, call that function:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <mat-form-field>                    
        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="NUM_VALOR_IVA" placeholder="Valor IVA" [value]="calcResult()" required>                  
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

PS: don't use `ngModel` for your form inputs if you are using `FormBuilder` (you can use it for other things on the same page).

Comment: thanks so much! this works !!
thank you very much, it worked perfect !! Here I leave the complete solution for someone who has the same

Comment: calcResult() {
    const o  = this.formDetalleOC.get('NUM_PRECIO_UNITARIO').value * this.formDetalleOC.get('NUM_PORCENTAJE_IVA').value;  
    this.formDetalleOC.patchValue({
      NUM_VALOR_IVA: o
    })
    return o 
}